# Do all the sockets in a namespace connect to the same port on the server in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, namespaces

I thought when a server is started, it creates a specific number of TCP ports on a computer. so whenever a new connection comes in, it assigns a port to that client ('connection'). Recently I opened tutorialsPoint website 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_namespaces.htm' and in there is written:

"Socket.IO allows you to “namespace” your sockets, which essentially means assigning different endpoints or paths. This is a useful feature to minimize the number of resources (TCP connections) and at the same time separate concerns within your application by introducing separation between communication channels. Multiple namespaces actually share the same WebSockets connection thus saving us socket ports on the server".

This part i did not understand: "Multiple namespaces actually share the same WebSockets connection thus saving us socket ports on the server". My question is how can all the connections share a single port on the web-server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do all the sockets in a namespace connect to the same port on the server in socket.io?

Yes, they do.

First off socket.io is built on the underlying webSocket protocol.  A webSocket connection starts with an http connection which is built on top of a TCP connection and then the two sides agree to "upgrade" the protocol to start talking the webSocket protocol instead of the http protocol.

So, when a socket.io connection comes in, it's initially an http connection.

Second, any TCP server is listening for inbound connections on a known port.  The client must know what that port is and the client attempts to connect to the combination of IP address and port.  A regular TCP server using only one network adapter will just be listening on that one port.  **All inbound client connections will arrive on that one port.**

> I thought when a server is started, it creates a specific number of TCP ports on a computer. so whenever a new connection comes in, it assigns a port to that client ('connection').

That's not how it works.  **A listening server creates a passive socket listening for inbound connections on one specific port**.  When a TCP client initiates an outbound connection, **that client picks a dynamically selected port number for that outbound connection** (that is unique for that client and not currently in use).  This source port number is typically not visible in TCP, http, webSocket or socket.io programming (though you can see what is is if you want - you just don't have to use it yourself at the level we usually program at).  It's part of the TCP plumbing that helps packets get delivered to the right socket.  So, at that point it has a source IP address and a source port number.  It then attempts to connect to a target IP address on a target port.

That unique combination of those four parameters:

```
 source IP
 source port (dynamically assigned on the client)
 target IP (known in advance by the client)
 target port (known in advance by the client)
```

defines a unique TCP connection.  No two TCP connections will have the same four parameters.  If the same client makes another TCP connection to the same target IP and port, it will be assigned a different source port number and thus it will be a different unique combination.

There's one little (somewhat confusing) aspect here that I'll make you aware of, but not try to overly explain or confuse things by.  Many clients are actually on a private network and have a private IP address.  That private IP address is not what the server actually sees as the source of the connection.  At some point the connection goes through a gateway that connects the private network to a public network.  This gateway will do NAT (network address translation).  It will swap the private source IP/port for a public source IP/port that corresponds to the gateway itself.  It remembers what it swapped so that when packets come back the other directly, it can swap it back. So, the target server actually believes it's communicating with the gateway, but anything the target sends to the gateway is "forwarded" onto the private IP address/port of the original sender.  So, you don't really need to understand the details of the gateway except that it's serves as a broker between the private IP address of some computer on a private network and some computer on the public internet that you are trying to connect to.  It does what's called "network address translation" to make this all work.  For the rest of the discussion, you should forget about this and just pretend that both source and target are both on the public internet with public IP addresses (even though that is almost never the actual case, but the gateway makes it just work as if they were).

> "Socket.IO allows you to “namespace” your sockets, which essentially means assigning different endpoints or paths. This is a useful feature to minimize the number of resources (TCP connections) and at the same time separate concerns within your application by introducing separation between communication channels. Multiple namespaces actually share the same WebSockets connection thus saving us socket ports on the server".

In socket.io, when you connect on a namespace, you are creating a new underlying webSocket connection to the same target IP/port.  A server can have many inbound connections to the same IP/port.  Each is given it's own TCP socket and the four parameters mentioned above uniquely define each one.  When an inbound network packet arrives at the lowest level, TCP can tell which source IP and source port it came from and which target IP/port is was sent  and that allows the TCP driver to figure out which socket that packet belongs to so that the packet can be delivered to the code that is monitoring that specific socket.

> This part i did not understand: "Multiple namespaces actually share the same WebSockets connection thus saving us socket ports on the server". My question is how can all the connections share a single port on the web-server.

To use a namespace in socket.io, you make a new socket.io connection to that specific namespace.  You don't use multiple namespaces on a single socket.io connection.  But, a namespace operates at a higher level than the TCP or webSocket connection logic.  It rides on top of that in the application layer.  So, all namespace connections, no matter which namespace you are using, connect to the same server on the same IP and same port.  Once the connection has been established, socket.io sends some data that it would like a "logical" connection on this namespace and then the receiving socket.io code is informed that the new connection belongs in this namespace.

Here's a useful article to read on the topic: [Understanding socket and port in TCP](https://medium.com/fantageek/understanding-socket-and-port-in-tcp-2213dc2e9b0c).

Comment: Thank you so much... You really cleared my confusion...  Here is what I understand: The URL(server URL) and the port on which the server is listening together form an endpoint and the server listens on this endpoint. So, when a socket connection comes in on this endpoint, it is actually on the same port as the endpoint is bound to this port. And also I think this is the reason that in the documentation is written "Multiple namespaces actually share the same WebSockets connection thus saving us socket ports on the server" as each namespace is a different endpoint having different ports.

Comment: @RayanReyaz - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.